# Cannot access my own public IP

Tags: networking, router, dns, ip

I will preface this by saying I use apache, although it hasnt worked with nginx, httpd, or other services.

I host a website on my server, its fully accessible by anyone and everyone*. The server is up, port 80 is up, and the site runs fine.

*Except me

For some reason, I cannot access my site, either by typing in the domain name, or going directly to my IP public adress, it times out.

If, however, I go to the LAN adress (192.168....), the site works fine. From the server, going to localhost also works fine.

If i connect to a different network (different public adress), then I can access the site.

Additional Information:

Port 80 is forwaded directly to the server

I use a seperate subnet for my servers (but accessing it from either subnets gives the same result). By this I mean i have a central modem where the cables from outside come in, which goes into another router in my room (the second subnet). I think this might be irrelavant since in my last home I only used 1 central router, no subnets, and still had the issue.

This same issue was prevalant at my last house, even though I used a different ISP and had a different router.

-----------EDIT:--------
So apparently this issue is called hairpinning, but I still have not found any resources on how to fix it.

Comment: Are you paying your ISP for a static IP address?

Comment: Yes, I have on statis IP adress that wont change.

Comment: I have heard about that kind of thing where with some routers you can access your own public IP and with some you can't.. https://docs.connectwise.com/ConnectWise_Control_Documentation/On-premises/On-premises_knowledge_base/Cannot_access_external_IP_address_from_LAN    and https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2240145-cannot-access-public-ip-while-connected-locally   it may be called NAT reflection or NAT loopback, something like that.

Comment: Net hairpinning should help you.

Comment: you could test from outside via your mobile phone connection, something I did more than once....

Answer (score 0):

I have heard about that kind of thing where with some routers you can access your own public IP and with some you can't.. https://docs.connectwise.com/ConnectWise_Control_Documentation/On-premises/On-premises_knowledge_base/Cannot_access_external_IP_address_from_LAN    and https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2240145-cannot-access-public-ip-while-connected-locally

"This can be done and requires a feature called NAT Reflection"

"Other terms for this are "NAT Hairpinning" and "NAT Loopback""

You need a router that has that feature.

Americans often like netgear routers, (though my experience in the UK and my ISP in the UK too, have found they haven't been so good), but  here is a list of netgear routers that support the feature. https://kb.netgear.com/000049578/Which-NETGEAR-routers-support-NAT-loopback

You could look up what routers support it. You could contact router manufacturers if you like a manufacturer or model and ask them if it supports NAT loopback / NAT hairpinning / NAT reflection.

Comment: I also had the same problem for a week before, and then asked a question too. And got an answer. There should be more articles about this.

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana often router manufacturers and ISPs that provide routers, have telephone numbers and can offer good advice.

Comment: I have solved it already. It was named NAT Loopback in my case.

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana so you had the option in your router?

Comment: yes I did have the option. It was a D-Link AC1200